# What kind of electronic device do I need?

Tags: switches

I'm looking for a switch that stays normally closed and when it receives power it stays closed for a few seconds before it opens. When power shuts off then the switch goes back to being closed. Is there an electronic device out there that will do this and can someone tell me the name of it

Comment: Consider a timer relay.

Comment: what do you mean by `closed`? ... conducting current?

Comment: When the power shuts off does it have to close immediately? This affects design choices since thermal delay devices delay in both directions.

Comment: @jsotola yes closed meaning allowing current to flow.

Comment: @gbarry a delay in both directions is acceptable.

Comment: @blah Question needs more detail. What do you mean by 'power'? The answer will be very different for 5 VDC than for 240 VAC. What is being switched? For all we know it could be mains voltage or a low level audio signal. Do you just need dry contacts? If so what voltage and current rating? What delay do you need? You say "a few seconds", can you give us a definite range? The more info about your requirements you give us the better the answer you will get. Please edit the question to add the info, don't just put it in the comments.

Comment: Delay-On Timer-Relay, and you'd use its Normally-Closed contacts.